# Determinant and non trivial solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{cases}
(2-c)y+z =0
\\y+(2-c)z =0
\end{cases}
$$

I do the determinant and get $c= 1, 3$
But for the system to have non trivial solutions, $c$ can't be 1 or 3, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you've got it backwards. The system has non-trivial solutions if and only if $c = 1$ or $c = 3$.

For instance, if $c = 1$, then the system is $\begin{cases}y+z = 0\\y+z = 0\end{cases}$, which has several solutions which are in the form $(y,z) = (t,-t)$ for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Also if $c = 3$, then the system is $\begin{cases}-y+z = 0\\y-z = 0\end{cases}$, which has several solutions which are in the form $(y,z) = (t,t)$ for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

For any other value of $c$, you can solve the system to get $(y,z) = (0,0)$ as the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong. The system will have nontrivial solutions *only* when $c=1$ or $c=3$.